# MSI GS75 with Ubuntu 18.04 -- Some fn keys not working (only volume / brightness work)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I have a msi stealth gs75 running ubuntu 18.04.

Only 4 fn key combos work, namely, the fn + arrow keys combos (volume up / down, brightness up / down).

All other fn combos dont work (i.e. fn + f1-f12, and fn + numpad -/+)

When I hold down the fn button, all the possible combo keys that work with it light up with a red backlit, which is cool, but only 4 of those that are lit actually work.

Any ideas on how to solve this without losing any functionality?

Comment: Same problem here, MSI Stealth GS66, with Ubuntu 20.04, Kernel 5.11.13.

Comment: As far as I can see `xev` does not register any events when I use fn+f1..f12. `xev` does echo events when I press fn+arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> switch between two different states (on/off). On the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, there is a small led that turns on and off, when switching modes. This gives you the feedback about the current mode.

When the led is off, <kbd>Fn</kbd> works with the <kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

```
That is right question i am looking for ;p
```

Maybe your laptop have **AMD** processor if i guessed correctly.

> I was stucked in the same condition. When i tried to run ubuntu in
> Asus A17 having AMD processor, and tried to install every possible
> software/ nvidia-latest-drivers / third party software/ renaming
> videoconfig or xconf files nothing can solve problem for that
> **BRIGHTNESS** issue.

Then one thing can solve my problem completely.

**1. Make ubuntu bootable usb with latest release.**

**2. Use wired internet or fibrenet to download all compatible drivers while installing ubuntu.** (for wireless network you have to configure manually)

*Now if u have data on your ubuntu then backup,
and install fresh new ubuntu os and remember having marked on the option download all drivers to resolve this issue while installation.*

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCxh2.png)

select the 2nd option too.

and then install. If somehow found any error then let me now in comments. I'll help ASAP.

```
 It was works for me and now keyboard backlight and brightness all fn's
 are working fine.
```